# Can i hook into significant location change service so that i can track a Phone latest location?

Tags: iphone, gps, hook

i would love to build a auto-start with OS app which runs in IOS background(like a daemon) and when the phone changed its location the app send some information(userid,GPS,time......)to a web server immediately, in addition to,i want my app has no icon and users can not easily find it is on running or easily delete it. so i just wondering if these is some location-change notification i can hook into so that i can perform my code? anyone give me a good idea? i dont want put my app on appstore instead of i packaged it in deb,so i can use any private api or other non-official methods....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CoreLocation` native framework.we can access the current location of the user/device dynamically. follow the link for instructions [coreLocation tutorials](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's Documents and guidelines, I don't think an app can exist without icon. The SDK doesn't have this feature as well. And no private API will be accepted into App Store. However, you can post your project on unofficial AppStores for jailbroken phones.